# Clash of clans attack strategy, farming or cupping?

Tags: clash-of-clans

1. I'm town hall level 7 and highest barracks of level and can hold up to 175 troops.  What would be the ideal troops to use in a attack, how many of them each?
2. Also, at town hall level 7, should I be heading to more trophies (cupping) as I've got 1350 or should I start farming, maxing out my village?

Answer (score 2):

Gaining Trophies has no benefits, people just drop trophies to go down an attack weaker villages for a lot amount of resources.

I think 1250 - 1400 is good for town hall 7

It's up to you that how you want to attack , what you are seeking and how you like to play.

If you want to gain trophies a giant-healer attack would be good. ( 15 Giant/2 Healer/ 25 barbarian / 15 goblin / rest archers )

But If you just want resources ( that I think you should ) , you better attack with archers-goblins-barbarians ( amount of each troop is depend on the level of that troop ) , you should bring some wall breaker in case storages is close to walls.

**Clash of clan's wiki :**

> **Army Planning :**
>   Army Planning is one of the most important parts of raiding. If your army is not planned out well enough you are probably going to lose, or at most earn one star. Depending on your objective (trophies or resources), you'll have to plan your army according to it.
>   If you're raiding for Trophies or a balance of Trophies or resources, this army configuration is decent for mid-level players (169 housing space required):
>
> - 1 Healer
> - 15 Giants
> - 40 Archers
> - 30 Barbarians
> - 10 Goblins
>
> If you're specifically farming for resources and don't care at all about Trophies, a typical army might look like the following (180 housing space required):
>
> - 30 Archers
> - 100 Goblins
> - 50 Barbarians
>
> Armies such as this are able to steal up to 350,000 Gold and Elixir (or more in some cases).

Comment: I don't know all the details from back when this post was created, but gaining trophies has the benefit of getting into a league; which in turns gives bonus loot upon being victorious against an attack. This bonus is bigger in the higher leagues. For a town hall 7, a bonus from the master leagues would be enormous.

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 healers and 152 high level barbarians and it can get you to gold which I am or I use 10 wallbreakers 10 barbarians for decoy and 150 goblins for farming

Answer (score 0):

If you are a town hall 7 person you can use 50 barbs and 50 archers and use 50 minions and now you can bam any base you like.

Answer (score -1):

You can farm using mass infantry to overrun easier bases or to pick off exposed collectors, mines or storages.

Answer (score -1):

I normally go with 180 goblins, but toss in a few wallbreakers and minions for a really good farming army

Comment: Why is that a good strategy? Adding your reasoning makes your answer better and more useful to other readers.

Answer (score -1):

I use 5 wall breakers and about 45 barb and 45 goblins and rest archers (150 troop capacity) i also have lvl 2 spell factory using 2 lightning or 1 heal 1 lightning btw go for revenge those cost no gold

Comment: To improve your answer, try to answer the following: Why do you use this strategy? Why does it work? What are some pros and cons?

Answer (score -1):

I'm around the same level and use 9 balloons, 9 giants, 5 wall breakers and 80 archers. It works out fine for me. You should be able to do so, at least remove a baloon or a giant and you'll do just fine.